# Google Smart Lock constantly asking to turn on Bluetooth

Tags: ios

I have Google Smart Lock installed on my iPad running under iOS 12.

Every now and then (up to a dozen times a day) the following system dialog window shows on top of whatever is active (this is not a foreground app-induced message):

> Turn On Bluetooth to Allow "Smart Lock" to Connect to Accessories

[image]

I do not want to have Bluetooth constantly enabled.

---

What is the reason and how can I prevent it from appearing?

---

Additional info:

- All my Google accounts show:

  > Your account has been securely set up on this phone.
- I have keys (YubiKey) configured for 2FA, which I use on PCs, but they are not Bluetooth enabled
- I did not have that problem before iOS 12, but coincidentally I had an iPad replaced at the time of iOS 12 release and I configured credentials only after upgrading

Answer (score 1):

I'm having the exact same problem and there are no references to it on the internet except this StackExchange post and a dupe post on another site.  I still don't understand why it's happening or what's causing it.  It doesn't appear to be tied use of any particular app, and sometimes pops up simply when I pick up my phone and unlock it.

I thought disabling Google Advanced Protection would make this go away.  However, even with it disabled and all hardware tokens removed entirely from my account, I *still* get the popup on my iPhone saying `"Turn On Bluetooth to Allow "Smart Lock" to Connect to Accessories"`.  I uninstalled the Smart Lock app and I haven't seen it pop up since.

So - my workaround is basically not using Google Advanced Protection at all.

I may attempt to re-enable it and do more troubleshooting when I have time.  One thing I forgot to do was go into my iPhone bluetooth settings and "forget" any previous pairings.  Maybe that has something to do with the popup if it's looking for a past device.  Will post edits here if anything changes!